# Android: how to get list item property with floating context menu item click

Tags: android, contextmenu, android-recyclerview

I have an activity with arraylist declaration

```
private ArrayList<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();
```

and inside onCreate

```
products.add(new Product("Product One",100, 1));
products.add(new Product("Product Two",200, 2));
products.add(new Product("Product Three",170, 3));
products.add(new Product("Product Four",220, 4));

ProductAdapter itemsAdapter = new ProductAdapter(this, products);
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
listView.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);
registerForContextMenu(listView);
```

in the Product class:

```
public class Product {
  private String mProductName;
  private int mProductPrice;
  private int mProductId;

  public Product(String productName, int productPrice, int productId){
    mProductName = productName;
    mProductPrice = productPrice;
    mProductId = productId;
  }

  public String getProductName(){
    return mProductName;
  }

  public int getProducId(){
    return mProductId;
  }

  public int getProductPrice(){
    return mProductPrice;
  }

}
```

And the adapter is simple to get the name and price of every product and view the list. Now in the activity I create the context menu like this

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
}
```

How can I get the long pressed item property like product id after selecting optipn from the context menu using "onContextItemSelected"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first set a global variable productId then on the listview long click listener set the product id. take a look at the sample code below.

```
int productId = 0;
lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, 
    View arg1,int pos, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           Product product =  
           (Product)arg0.getAdapter().getItem(position)
           productId = product.mProductId; 
           return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: but this code doesn't display the floating context menu it gets the product id when the user long clicks on an item. I want to get the product id of the product which displays the floating context menu.